# Why do some USB drives turn into 0 byte storage devices instead of ejecting?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have two [PNY Turbo Attaché 3 USB 3.0 Flash Drives](https://www.pny.com/usb3-elite-turbo-silver?sku=P-FD32GTBOP-GE). When I try to eject either of them, they don’t get ejected. Instead, the device resizes itself to become zero bytes large. If I try to eject the device again, it just stays connected as a zero byte large storage device. Physically disconnecting and reconnecting the drive returns it to its original 32GB state.

I’m able to observe this behavior on Linux using [`eject`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/eject.1) and [`lsblk`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/lsblk.8) and on Windows using Windows Explorer and [`diskpart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart). What’s especially weird is that the PNY drives aren’t the only ones I have that do this. I have USB drives from two other manufacturers that do the same thing.

What’s going on here? Shouldn’t the devices disappear completely when they’re ejected?

Comment: Having *never* seen that behavior, either on Windows or Linux, my guess is that they have somewhat broken controllers, q.v.: https://www.techtarget.com/searchstorage/definition/flash-controller . However, I've seen in Windows that the built-in "Safely Remove Hardware & Eject Media" utility occasionally fails, so I use  third-party tool, HotSwap, instead.

Comment: They're probably something like a USB card reader with a MicroSD card fitted. Card readers generally allow you to eject the card that is fitted rather than the whole device. That said I'd be surprised to see this in a proper USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of experimenting, I think that I can partially answer this question.

Every drive is different. My conclusions are based on testing I did with these drives:

- [Team Group Color Turn (E902) USB 3.0 [8GB]](https://web.archive.org/web/20151009025702/http://www.teamgroupinc.com/en/product/USBDrives/USB3.0/Color%20Turn(E902))
- [Nitrokey Storage 2 [16GB]](https://shop.nitrokey.com/shop/product/nitrokey-storage-2-56)
- [SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 Flash Drive [16GB]](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/usb-flash-drives/sandisk-ultra-usb-3-0#SDCZ48-016G-U46)
- [PNY Turbo Attaché 3 USB 3.0 Flash Drive [32GB]](https://www.pny.com/usb3-elite-turbo-silver?sku=P-FD32GTBOP-GE)
- [Kingston DataTraveler Max Type A Flash Drive [256GB]](https://shop.kingston.com/collections/usb-flash-drives/products/datatraveler-max-usb-c-flash-drive?variant=42956759335104)

Each of those drives does something that I wouldn’t expect when I eject it using [`eject`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/eject.1) on Linux or Windows Explorer on Windows. Not all of them resize themselves to 0 bytes, though.

### Part 1: What’s going on here?

[@Mokubai suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/1761089/why-do-some-usb-drives-turn-into-0-byte-storage-devices-instead-of-ejecting?noredirect=1#comment2738073_1761089) “They're probably something like a USB card reader with a MicroSD card fitted. Card readers generally allow you to eject the card that is fitted rather than the whole device.” [The Nitrokey Storage 2 is indeed a MicroSD card reader with a built-in MicroSD card.](https://support.nitrokey.com/t/nitrokey-storage-bring-your-own-storage/4339) I don’t know about the other drives, though.

### Part 2: Shouldn’t the devices disappear completely when they’re ejected?

Perhaps not. It depends on what “eject” means and whether or not your ejecting the USB device itself. When I wrote the question, here’s what I meant by “eject”:

1. If there’s any mounted filesystems on the device, unmount them or stop and display an error.
2. Make sure that any remaining data is written to the device.
3. Cleanly shut down the device.

As it turns out, what I was telling Linux and Windows to do wasn’t that three step process.

On Linux, I was using the `eject` command. [Its man page says “There are four different methods of ejecting, depending on whether the device is a CD-ROM, SCSI device, removable floppy, or tape. By default **eject** tries all four methods in order until it succeeds.”](https://man.archlinux.org/man/eject.1) None of those methods are USB-specific. From what I can tell, `eject` is just concerned with shutting down the storage itself, not the entire USB device. Now, shutting down the storage itself should probably shut down the entire USB device, but, as [@DrMoishe Pippik mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/1761089/why-do-some-usb-drives-turn-into-0-byte-storage-devices-instead-of-ejecting?noredirect=1#comment2738071_1761089), these devices might just have broken flash controllers.

On Windows, I was using Windows Explorer to try and eject drive `E:` (for example). It’s important to note that “drive” letters don’t refer to drives. They refer to volumes. (You can verify this yourself using [`diskpart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart). In `diskpart`, first run `list disk` then run `list volume`.) So when you ask to eject “drive” `E:`, you’re not asking to shut down the entire USB device. You’re just asking to shutdown a specific volume. That being said, Windows defaults to creating an MBR partition table with a single partition on USB drives. The volume in this case doesn’t span the entire drive since part of the drive is being used by the MBR. Ejecting it via Windows Explorer sill resizes the entire drive to zero bytes, so, even though you’re just asking to do something with part of the storage space, you end up doing something with the all of the storage space. Either way, Windows explorer is working with the storage space on the USB device, not with the entire USB device.

### Part 3: How to cleanly shut down a USB drive on Linux and Windows

As I mentioned before, it seems like I don’t actually want to “eject” these drives. So how do I do what I actually want to do?

##### On Linux

```bash
udisksctl power-off --block-device=/dev/<whatever>
```

According to [`udisksctl`’s man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/udisksctl.1), `udiskctl power-off` does exactly what I want to do:

> **power-off**
>
> Arranges for the drive to be safely removed and powered off. On the OS side this includes ensuring that no process is using the drive, then requesting that in-flight buffers and caches are committed to stable storage. The exact steps for powering off the drive depends on the drive itself and the interconnect used. For drives connected through USB, the effect is that the USB device will be deconfigured followed by disabling the upstream hub port it is connected to.
>
> Note that as some physical devices contain multiple drives (for example 4-in-1 flash card reader USB devices) powering off one drive may affect other drives. As such there are not a lot of guarantees associated with performing this action. Usually the effect is that the drive disappears as if it was unplugged.

[(Thanks to @don_crissti for helping me figure that out).](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444730/316181)

##### On Windows 11

1. Find the “Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media” tray icon.

   [image: It looks like a USB drive with a check mark on its lower right corner.]
2. Right click on it.

   [image: When you right click, a context menu will appear.]
3. Click the option that says “Eject” followed by the name of the drive.

   [image: The drive I’m using in this example is named “USB 3.2.1 FD”.]
4. Open the Settings app.
5. In the sidebar, click “Bluetooth & devices”.

   [image: “Bluetooth & devices” is below “System” and above “Network & internet”.]
6. Click “View more devices”.

   [image: The “View more devices” button is beneath a large square labeled “Add device”.]
7. To the right of the USB drive, there should be a button with an ellipsis on it. Click on that button.

   [image: If you hover over the ellipsis button, the words “More options” will appear.]
8. Click “Remove device”.

   [image: The “Remove device” button should have appeared above the ellipsis button.]
9. Click “Yes”.

   [image: The box where you need to click “Yes” says “Are you sure you want to remove this device?]